# Why are my desktop applications children of PID1

Tags: linux, systemd, process, desktop

I'm launching my graphical applications with `i3bar`. When I look at my system's process tree with `pstree`,I can see my graphical applications (Firefox, Chromium, Termite etc) are all children of `systemd` (PID1) and not of `i3bar`. Shouldn't they be children of `i3bar` given that they are launched by it?

Answer (score 1):

[Taking a look at the i3bar source](https://github.com/i3/i3/blob/next/i3bar/src/child.c#L557), it appears that when i3bar starts a new application it does the following:

1. `fork()`
2. makes a call to [setpgid](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setpgid.2.html), with the new group id = 0 (see comments on the manpage for this behavior)
3. `execl()`

So the new child process should have the same parent as i3bar since it is promoted to the parent's process group.

You can verify this by checking the process group id of the i3bar instance. For example:

```
ps axo pid,ppid,pgid,sid,comm | grep i3bar
# See 3rd column
```

If i3bar is also a child of init, then this would explain the behavior you are seeing.